# How to use the Chef knife utility from a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife

I just experimented with a Windows batch file that executes several knife commands, and it is not working.  The batch file executes the first command and then stops.

Here is the knife version:

```
C:\Data\SVN\dev\trunk\chef-repo> knife -v
Chef: 11.10.0
```

Here is the batch file, knife_cookbooks.bat:

```
knife cookbook upload apt
knife cookbook upload ntp
knife cookbook upload sudo
knife cookbook upload sysctl
```

And the output:

```
C:\Data\SVN\dev\trunk\chef-repo> knife_cookbooks.bat

C:\Data\SVN\dev\trunk\chef-repo> knife cookbook upload apt
Uploading apt            [2.3.8]
Uploaded 1 cookbook.
```

The same thing happens with other *knife* commands.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Do you need to && the commands together?

Comment: I use spiceweasel to generate my knife commands. Highly recommended: https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sethvargo for the tip about using "&&".  Combining that with the line-continuation character "^" for readability did the trick.

I modified the batch file as follows, and it works!

```
knife cookbook upload apt && ^
knife cookbook upload ntp && ^
knife cookbook upload sudo && ^
knife cookbook upload sysctl
```

**Update**: I told a co-worker about this problem, and he said "Is knife a batch file?  If so, use *call* when invoking it."  So I checked, and yes indeed, knife is actually *knife.bat*.  So I modified my batch file, and this form also works:

```
call knife cookbook upload apt 
call knife cookbook upload ntp 
call knife cookbook upload sudo 
call knife cookbook upload sysctl
```